# How to especify the query in a hasMany relashionship in Grails?

Tags: hibernate, grails, grails-orm, grails-2.0, grails-domain-class

I have this domain class in Grails:

```
class User {
   String name

   Status status
   enum Status {
    ACTIVE(1),
    BLOCKED(2)
   }

 static hasMany = [friends:User]
}
```

So user can have one or more friends (User).

When I do something like this:

```
User someone = User.get(1)
someone.friends // all friends from this user
```

But I want to get friends only with status is ACTIVE. How can I specify this in domain class?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Override the `getFriends()` method. This is not tested of course.

```
Set<User> getFriends() {

User.executeQuery("Select f from User u join u.friends as f where u = :user and  f.status = :status", [user: this, status: Status.ACTIVE])

}
```

Comment: I would avoid overriding the getter for the association, as you might want to access inactive friends sometimes. Adding an inactive User via addToFriends or setting the whole collection via setFriends could create some confusion when calling getFriends(). Define getActiveFriends() instead. I know that's what he asked, I'm just adding my .02$